# Convert OkHttp's Form Data (Android) to Axios(React Native)'s Form Data

Tags: android, react-native, axios, multipartform-data, okhttp

I'm recreating a project that was originally designed for Native Android to use React Native. There is an endpoint that is responsible to send a image using Form Data. I tried to convert the OkHttp3's Form Data to Axios's Form Data and I'm getting an error from backend saying that the request fields doesn't match.
My Code so far:

- **Native Android(original app):**

```
public RequestResponse<Boolean> functionApi(@NonNull String id, String imageExtension, @NonNull byte[] imageData, @NonNull String anotherData) throws ServerErrorException, IOException, AuthenticationException {
        String path = "route/" + id;

        Pair<String, String> contentTypeHeader = new Pair<>("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("anotherData", anotherData)
                .addFormDataPart("imageData", id + "." + imageExtension, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), imageData))
                .build();
        Response response = MyHttpClient.execute(path, "POST", requestBody, contentTypeHeader);
        String body = response.body().string();

        RequestResponse<Boolean> r = responseBodyToObject(body, RequestResponse.class);

        r.setBody(r.getStatus() != RequestResponse.ERROR);

        return r;
    }
```

**React Native(new app) version:**

```
export const functionApi = async(id,imageExtension,imageData,anotherData)=>{
    try{
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('anotherData',anotherData)
        formData.append('imageData',`data:image/${imageExtension};base64,${imageData}`,`${id}.${imageExtension}`)
//imageData here i tried to use a base64's string
        let res = await axios({
            url:`${URL_SERVER}/route/${id}`,
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':"multipart/form-data"
            },
            data:formData
        })
        return res['data']
    }catch(err){
        return getErrorMessage(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting errors from backend saying that the fields weren't valid

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that finally worked for me:

```
export const functionApi = async(id,imageExtension,imageData,anotherData)=>{
    try{
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('anotherData',anotherData)
        formData.append('imageData',{
            uri: imageData['uri'],
            type: 'image/jpg',
            name: `${id}.${imageExtension}`,
        })
        let res = await axios({
            url:`${URL_SERVER}/route/${id}`,
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data:formData
        })
        return res['data']
    }catch(err){
        return getErrorMessage(err)
    }
}
```